# Remove logging query from app.config file

Tags: database, log4net

I am using Log4Net to log exception to database. It works fine but i have to specify below log insertion query to app.config file.

```
<commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],
                       [Message],[Exception],[Username],,[MethodName]) 
                    VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, 
                            @message, @exception,@username,@methodname)" />
```

How can i remove this query from configuration file and specify it to from code.

I am using  a C# desktop application.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
public static class LogConfigurator
{
    public static void SetCommandText(string commandText)
    {
        Hierarchy logHierarchy = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository()
                                 as Hierarchy;

        if (logHierarchy == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Can't set command text as log4net has not been configured");
        }

        // assume there is only one appender to configure
        var appender = logHierarchy.GetAppenders()
                                   .OfType<AdoNetAppender>()
                                   .SingleOrDefault();

        if (appender == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException
                ("Can't set command text as can't locate a database appender");
        }

        appender.CommandText = commandText;
        appender.ActivateOptions();
    }
}
```